# Check If Null Operator In Depth

Tags: c#

This is the statement with that null operator thingy.

```
this.Str = this.Str ?? "test";
```

I know that when str is null the "test" string value will be set to str variable.

So far so good but the actual question is what is happening when str is not null in first place.

Is this happening under the hood if str is not null?

```
this.Str = this.Str
```

That would mean the setter will be called anyway, right? Futhermore the custom logic I have in setter will be called even though the value hasnt changed, right?

I am hoping setter is not being called with the same value if str is not null.

Does somebody have a deep knowledge about this?

Sorry if this is a duplicate please let me know in comments and I will remove this question.

Comment: 1. It's called the null coalescing operator. 2. This would be trivial to test for yourself, no?

Comment: I am not in front of a pc. I am on vacation with my tablet. You are right I could have tested this but I would like to see your opinions about this and I would like to get a better explaination about this from you experts.

Comment: http://ideone.com/1WMa9h. It's not up for debate or subject to opinion. The documentation is clear enough.

Comment: I hope, your setter contains smth like `if (str != value) {}`? Anyway, why to use null coalescing here? Why just don't write `if (Str != null)`, or, which is usually more accurate for strings, `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Str))`?

Comment: @Dennis I am just asking because I recently saw this null operator thingy. I would like to know what is it doing in background

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setter will be called. You have two operators here - *null-coalescing* operator which is executed first and evaluated to value returned by `Str` getter or `"test"` string. Second operator is *assignment* operator which passes evaluated value to `Str` setter.

If you don't want custom logic to be executed then check assigned value manually:

```
public string Str
{
    get { returns _str; }
    set
    {
        if (_str == value)
            return;

        _str = value;
        // custom logic
    }
}
```

That will allow you to run custom logic only when property value *changes* instead of each time you assign something to property.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The setter is always called in this case. You must be able to do validation, even if the value is the same.

Another thingy, if the string isn't null but empty, you can try this:

```
this.Str = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Str) ? this.Str : "test";
```

This code will work for both:

```
this.Str = null;
this.Str = "";
```

Comment: Yeah thanks Patrick, I knew about that statement before. I recently saw this null operator thingy and I have no experience with it so far so that is why I am asking this question.